# Ошибка urlpatterns

Tags: django

django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: The included URLconf 'JsonApi.urls' does not appear to have any patterns in it. If you see valid patterns in the file then the issue is probably caused by a circular import.

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from django.conf.urls import url, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'json-input/', include('json_input.urls'))
]
```

---

```
Exception in thread django-main-thread:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/mac/Documents/JsonApi/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 589, in url_patterns
    iter(patterns)
TypeError: 'module' object is not iterable

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 916, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 864, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/Users/mac/Documents/JsonApi/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 53, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/mac/Documents/JsonApi/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 117, in inner_run
    self.check(display_num_errors=True)
  File "/Users/mac/Documents/JsonApi/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 395, in check
    include_deployment_checks=include_deployment_checks,
  File "/Users/mac/Documents/JsonApi/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 382, in _run_checks
    return checks.run_checks(**kwargs)
  File "/Users/mac/Documents/JsonApi/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/checks/registry.py", line 72, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)
  File "/Users/mac/Documents/JsonApi/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 40, in check_url_namespaces_unique
    all_namespaces = _load_all_namespaces(resolver)
  File "/Users/mac/Documents/JsonApi/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 57, in _load_all_namespaces
    url_patterns = getattr(resolver, 'url_patterns', [])
  File "/Users/mac/Documents/JsonApi/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 48, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/Users/mac/Documents/JsonApi/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 596, in url_patterns
    raise ImproperlyConfigured(msg.format(name=self.urlconf_name))
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: The included URLconf 'JsonApi.urls' does not appear to have any patterns in it. If you see valid patterns in the file then the issue is probably caused by a circular import.
```

---

json_input/urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views
from drf_yasg.views import get_schema_view
from drf_yasg import openapi
from rest_framework import permissions
from django.urls import path

schema_view = get_schema_view(
   openapi.Info(
      title="JSON API",
      default_version='v1',
      description="Test description",
      terms_of_service="https://www.google.com/policies/terms/",
      contact=openapi.Contact(email="contact@snippets.local"),
      license=openapi.License(name="BSD License"),
   ),
   public=True,
   permission_classes=(permissions.AllowAny,),
)

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^swagger(?P<format>\.json|\.yaml)$', schema_view.without_ui(cache_timeout=0), name='schema-json'),
    url(r'^swagger/$', schema_view.with_ui('swagger', cache_timeout=0), name='schema-swagger-ui'),
    url(r'^redoc/$', schema_view.with_ui('redoc', cache_timeout=0), name='schema-redoc'),
]
```

иерархия проекта
https://i.stack.imgur.com/2HTtj.jpg

В чем может быть ошибка?

Comment: Вы хоть расскажите, где какие файлы у вас расположены, а то этот кусок кода непонятно откуда и непонятно что с ним делать

Comment: @andreymal это файл urls.py самого проекта, в нем подключаются урлы приложения, то почему-то при запуске сервера происходит данная ошибка, при этом без добавления урлов приложения сервер успешно запускается

Comment: `json_input.urls` покажите

Comment: @ЕвгенийРогов «самого проекта» это слишком неконкретно, интересуют точные пути и вообще иерархия всего этого проекта

Comment: @m0nte-cr1st0 написал в запросе сверху

Comment: @andreymal прикрепил ссылку на скрин иерархии